# How to parse or download a large XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I want to parse or download an XML file. The file is an XML feed.

I have tried to parse the file like this:

```
$this->url = 'https://example.com/feed.xml';
$reader = XMLReader::open($this->url);
while ($reader->read()) {
  if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT) {

  // Get the value of first attribute
  $value = $reader->getAttributeNo(0);

  // Output the value to browser
  echo $value . "<br>";
  }
}
```

But nothing happens. There is no output.
I am expecting to get the key and values of the tags in the xml file printed, like:

```
12345 // that is the <g:id>
Product1 // that is the <title>
Long description // that is the <description>
1 // that is the <g:google_product_category>
```

I also tried this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// look for the first "item" element node
while (
  $reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'item'
) {
  continue;
}

while ($reader->localName === 'item') {
  $domItem = $reader->expand($document);
  echo "\nId: " . $xpath->evaluate('string(g:id)', $domItem);
}
```

But there is also no output.
Here I am expecting to get this output:

```
Id: 12345
Id: 123456
```

I wonder if this is right. XMLReader should read the XML file line by line, isn't it?

Then I tried to download the XML file:

```
if (file_put_contents('./feed.xml', file_get_contents(self::PROD_URL))) {
  echo "File saved successfully";
} else {
  echo "File saving failed.";
}
```

But it said,

"File saving failed".
If I open the file "feed.xml" which have been created, I expect to see the content of the xml example. If I try it with a smaller xml file it is saved.

The XML file looks like this. It has many . I want to get all the  elements with their nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<atom:link href="https://example.com/feed.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<title>My feed</title>
<description>Discover the incredible ...</description>
<link>https://example.com</link>
<language>de-DE</language>
<image>
  <url>https://example.com/media/logo.png</url>
  <title>example.com</title>
  <link>https://example.com</link>
</image>
<item>
  <g:id>12345</g:id>
  <title>Product 1</title>
  <description>Long description</description>
  <g:google_product_category>1</g:google_product_category>
<item>
<item>
  <g:id>123456</g:id>
  <title>Product 2</title>
  <description>Long description</description>
  <g:google_product_category>2</g:google_product_category>
<item>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

What is the way to go?
May be the max_execution_time must be higher.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your exact expected output based on the xml in the question?

Comment: In your code, where you try to download the XML file, the error text is wrong. It should say: _"File saving failed."_. It might have downloaded fine, but couldn't be saved locally. We basically don't know whether your server is able to download the file.

Comment: I have added the expected output and adjust the error text.

Comment: "Large" is just imprecise as could be, so please give some proper info about what that actually means, at least roughly. (2, 3 digit number of MB? More? Into the GB range?) And do you have PHP error reporting turned up to the max?

Comment: I found the solution. The xml is generated by a route on the fly. So, I first have to use curl to call the route and then save the response as an xml file.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You second approach is the better one but it is missing some parts.

If you are using namespace, register and use your own aliases for them. They can match the aliases used in the XML document, but they do not have to. The namespace URI (e.g. `http://base.google.com/ns/1.0`) identifies a namespace - not the alias/prefix.

Do not forget to call `read()` or `next()` inside the loop to navigate to through the document.

```php
<?php

// convert test data into URL
$url = getXMLDataURL();

// define your own prefixes for the used namespaces
$xmlns = [
    'gbase' => 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0',
    'atom' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
];


// prepare DOM document for expanded nodes
$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register defined namespaces
foreach ($xmlns as $alias => $namespace) {
    $xpath->registerNamespace($alias, $namespace);
}

// open URI in reader
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($url);

// look for the first "item" element node
while (
  $reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'item'
) {
  continue;
}

// while here is an item element
while ($reader->localName === 'item') {
  // expand into DOM    
  $itemNode = $reader->expand($document);
  
  // use xpath to fetch nodes / values
  echo "\nId: " . $xpath->evaluate('string(gbase:id)', $itemNode);
  
  // navigate to next sibling "item"
  $reader->next('item');
}



function getXMLDataURL(): string {
    $data = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<atom:link href="https://example.com/feed.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<title>My feed</title>
<description>Discover the incredible ...</description>
<link>https://example.com</link>
<language>de-DE</language>
<image>
  <url>https://example.com/media/logo.png</url>
  <title>example.com</title>
  <link>https://example.com</link>
</image>
<item>
  <g:id>12345</g:id>
  <title>Product 1</title>
  <description>Long description</description>
  <g:google_product_category>1</g:google_product_category>
</item>
<item>
  <g:id>123456</g:id>
  <title>Product 2</title>
  <description>Long description</description>
  <g:google_product_category>2</g:google_product_category>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
XML;
  return 'data://application/atom+xml;base64,'.base64_encode($data);  
}
```